# Setting the @component bean name in mapstruct mapper

Tags: mapstruct

I know I can create a mapper like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface MyMapper{
```

That will result in:

```
@Component
public class MyMapperImpl{
```

How can I set the bean name obtaining:

```
@Component("name")
public class MyMapperImpl{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported. This is issue [mapstruct/mapstruct#1427](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1427) requested for this feature.

Depending on how your name should look like you can use a custom `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` to generate the mappers that are component scanned.

Starting from MapStruct 1.6 (1.6.0.Beta1 is already released) it is possible to use the new `@AnnotateWith`

e.g.

```java
@AnnotateWith(value = Service.class, elements = @Element(strings = "myMapperV2")
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface MyMapper {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In the end I just, for this mapper, used Mappers.getMapper(..)

Comment: The feature is already [implemented](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/2792), but is not part of a release yet. It probably will be part of **1.5.3**. The fix would be adding `@AnnotateWith(value = Service.class, elements = @Element(strings = "cakeMapperV2"))` to your mapper.

Comment: The feature won't be part of 1.5.3, but of 1.6. However, the example for how it'll work is correct. I'll update the answer once 1.6 is out

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bean mapper's *(by the implementationName field)* name as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Mapper(
        implementationName = "SubStepMapperImpl",
       )
public abstract class StepMapper {
    public abstract List<StepRepresentation> toRepresentation(final List<Step> steps);

}
```